# Como resolver error: "Fatal Error: Clase Jparameter no funciona"

Tags: joomla3

Estoy usando Joomla, luego de hacer una actualización de la versión 2.5 a la versión 3.0 obtengo los siguientes errores, puede que el JParameter no exista o se use de forma distinta en la versión 3.0?

```
Fatal error: Class 'JParameter' not found.
Fatal error: Clase 'JParameter' no funciona.
```

Comment: Agrega tu código en donde haces uso de JParameter para ayudarte a cambiar el código ya que si migraste a 3.0 ya no existe la clase!, ve mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

La clase **`JParameter` fue removida de Joomla versión 3.0** puedes usar **[JRegistry](https://docs.joomla.org/API17:JRegistry)**

> Joomla 3.0 **JParameter**: utilizar **JForm** en su lugar o, en la mayoría de las
>   circunstancias, **JRegistry** - por ejemplo, para recuperar en un
>   componente de un parámetro de plug-in)